# How to get url matching templates from a request context

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

There are jersey-2 dynamically building endpoint RESTful resources.
Path method

```
resourceBuilder.path("item/{id}");
```

defines a matching url pattern for a particular resource. E.g. when www.myapp.com/api/item/22 resource is requested, a handler with path pattern described above will process request.

I need to find out which path pattern (here it's "item/{id}") the requesting call will match.

getMatchedResources() or getMatchedURIs() don't provide list of path patterns.

```
methodBuilder.produces(new MediaType("text", "plain"))
.handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {

    @Override
    public String apply(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {

        List<Object> resources = ctx.getUriInfo().getMatchedResources();
        List<String> uris = ctx.getUriInfo().getMatchedURIs();

        return "Programmatically generated endpoint";
    }
});
```

Did anyone solve similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dynamically generating the endpoints you can do this in several ways. These are two ways to accomplish the same.

**First Approach:**

Creating a custom Inflector:

```
    // Special type of Inflector that's aware of the resource path. Users extending this class implement the
    // apply(data, resourcePath) method. Internally it uses a custom resource registry to get the resource path.
    public static abstract class PathAwareInflector<RESULT> implements Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, RESULT> {

        @Inject
        private ResourceRegistry resourceRegistry;
        private String resourcePath;

        @Override
        public final RESULT apply(ContainerRequestContext data) {
            return apply(data, getResourcePath(data));
        }

        public abstract RESULT apply(ContainerRequestContext data, String resourcePath);

        private String getResourcePath(ContainerRequestContext data) {
            if (resourcePath == null) {
                resourcePath = resourceRegistry.forPath(data.getUriInfo().getPath(true))
                    .stream()
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(Resource::getPath)
                    .orElse("UNKNOWN");
            }
            return resourcePath;
        }
    }
```

You can then register your resources like this:

```
    final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder("/item/{id}");
    final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET");
    methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
        .handledBy(new PathAwareInflector<String>() {

            @Override
            public String apply(ContainerRequestContext context, String resourcePath) {
                return resourcePath + "\n";
            }
        });

    registerResources(resourceBuilder.build());
```

**Second Approach**

Using a custom annotation `@ResourcePath` you define your method like this:

```
// Simple Endpoint with one method. Uses special custom @ResourcePath annotation to inject the resource path in two ways:
// As method argument, and as field using the same annotation. In a real world scenario you'd user either or.
public static class Endpoint {

    @ResourcePath
    String resourcePath2;

    public String endpoint(ContainerRequestContext context, @ResourcePath String resourcePath) {
        return resourcePath2 + " - " + resourcePath + "\n";
    }
}
```

And you register it like this:

```
    // This resource is configured through a class method. While the path, method, and produces are defined here,
    // the Endpoint.endpoint method actually handles the resource, which class and parameters can be annotated.
    final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder1 = Resource.builder("/annotation/{id}");
    final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder1 = resourceBuilder1.addMethod("GET");
    methodBuilder1.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
        .handledBy(Endpoint.class, Endpoint.class.getMethod("endpoint", ContainerRequestContext.class, String.class));

    registerResources(resourceBuilder1.build());
```

To support this mechanisms you'll need to have also this classes:

```
// Custom annotation used by ResourcePathInjectionResolver and ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider to
// inject field and parameters annotated with this annotation.
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface ResourcePath {

}


// It registers providers/injection resolvers/factories to enable @ResourcePath and PathAwareInflector
public static class PathResourceFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new ResourceRegistry.Binder());
        context.register(ResourceRegistry.Processor.class);
        context.register(new ResourcePathInjectionResolver.Binder());
        context.register(ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider.class);
        return true;
    }
}

// Custom injector that resolves @ResourcePath annotations for field injection. It delegates to
// ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider extending a ParamInjectionResolver.
public static class ResourcePathInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<ResourcePath> {

    static final class Binder extends AbstractBinder {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ResourcePathInjectionResolver.class)
                .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<ResourcePath>>() {
                })
                .in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }

    public ResourcePathInjectionResolver() {
        super(ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider.class);
    }
}

// Custom Factory Provider that resolves @ResourcePath annotations for parameter injection. It
// uses a custom Resource Registry to find the actual path.
public static class ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {

    public static class ResourcePathValueFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<String> {

        @Inject
        private ResourceRegistry resourceRegistry;

        public ResourcePathValueFactory() {
        }

        @Override
        public String provide() {
            return resourceRegistry.forPath(getContainerRequest().getPath(true))
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(Resource::getPath)
                .orElse(null);
        }
    }

    @Inject
    public ResourcePathValueFactoryProvider(MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider mpep, ServiceLocator locator) {
        super(mpep, locator, Parameter.Source.values());
    }

    @Override
    protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
        if (parameter.isAnnotationPresent(ResourcePath.class)) {
            return new ResourcePathValueFactory();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// Resource registry that stores the Resource Model and its configuration. It is bootstrapped with custom ModelProcessor
// that simply stores the resource model into the registry.
public static class ResourceRegistry {

    private ResourceModel resourceModel;

    private void setResourceModel(ResourceModel resourceModel) {
        this.resourceModel = resourceModel;
    }

    protected List<Resource> forPath(String path) {
        return resourceModel.getResources()
            .stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getPathPattern().match("/" + path) != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static final class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ResourceRegistry.class)
                .to(ResourceRegistry.class)
                .in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }

    public static class Processor implements ModelProcessor {

        private ResourceRegistry resourceRegistry;

        @Inject
        public Processor(ResourceRegistry resourceRegistry) {
            this.resourceRegistry = resourceRegistry;
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceModel processResourceModel(ResourceModel resourceModel, Configuration configuration) {
            resourceModel.getResources().stream().forEach(r -> {
                System.out.println("Path: " + r.getPath());
                System.out.println("Regex: " + r.getPathPattern().getRegex());
            });
            resourceRegistry.setResourceModel(resourceModel);
            return resourceModel;
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceModel processSubResource(ResourceModel subResourceModel, Configuration configuration) {
            return subResourceModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And register the Feature in your configuration:

```
    //Registers the Path Resource Feature that enables the functionality.
    register(PathResourceFeature.class);
```

Comment: I did, the path is going to be "item/22" when I need to find out that a pattern "item/{id}" will be a match for this path.

Comment: What you have in your question is not what im talking about. I'm talking about an interceptor for all endpoints

Comment: Can you talk about the question then? There is no problem to add a filter and intercept requests, the problem is to look up resources for matching patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retrieve matched templates from the context of the request by casting it to ContainerRequest and then calling getMatchedTemplates() method.

```
methodBuilder.produces(new MediaType("text", "plain"))
    .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>() {

    @Override
    public String apply(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {

        List<UriTemplate> uriTemplates =  ((ContainerRequest) requestContext).getUriInfo().getMatchedTemplates();
        if(uriTemplates != null && uriTemplates.size() > 0)
        {
            UriTemplate uriTemplate = uriTemplates.get(0);
            String pathTemplate = uriTemplate.getTemplate();

            //pathTemplate == "/item/{id}"
        }

        return "Programmatically generated endpoint";
   }
});
```

Comment: For this to be useful to future readers it would be helpful to add some explanation of what your code does to answer your question